# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS won't recognise AMD R9 290 using PCI riser

Tags: pci, amdgpu, lspci

I've installed amdgpu-pro, nothing changes
doesn't show in clinfo or lspci.

IF I plug GPU directly into mobo (no riser) the card is listed in lspci.

GIGABYTE GA Z170X UD3 v1

should I be installing drivers for the riser?

Comment: There are no drivers for such "bridges" (a riser is what you mean, perhaps?).

Comment: my mistake @MichaelBay - a riser was definitely what I meant. 

The risers worked when I had the machine running windows 10. These are the risers I'm currently using...

[link] (http://www.elegiants.com/ELEGIANT-PCI-E-USB-3_0-Cable-Express-1X-to-16X-Extension-Cable-p-203.html)

I am aware risers are notorious for failing... I have tried 4 backup risers & cables. 

I appreciate the response